# how C++ insert like python?

Tags: python, c++, vector, insert

I want to implement `insert` in `C++` like this:

```
// python code
insertIndexes = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
arr = []

toInsertValue = 0;
for i in insertIndexes:
    arr.insert(i, toInsertValue)
    toInsertValue += 1
print arr // [0, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2]
```

but I find that I have to know vector size if I want to use insert in `C++`:

```
// !!C++ wrong code!!
// vec is not initialized correctly
vector<int> vec;
int insertIndexes[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5}
int toInsertValue = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(insertIndexes)/sizeof(insertIndexes[0]); i++) {
    vec.insert(vec.begin() + insertIndexes[i], toInsertValue);
    toInsertValue += 1;
}
```

Comment: `int indexes = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5}` ? Nahhh.... That code is ill-formed.

Comment: If you have an array you can use [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) to get iterators to the array, and use [the range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) or just about any [standard algorithm function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) expecting a range defined by a pair of iterators.

Comment: what is your output & expected output?

Comment: @WhiZTiM my fault

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre python code will output this: `[0, 1, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2]`

Comment: You have the arguments to `insert()` backwards. The position is first, the value is second.

Comment: @Barmar You should make it as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar I think that's already known, the array `indexes` is an array of indexes into the vector, and `offset` is the value to insert.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude He's not indexing into it, he's using the `insert()` method. Is that allowed to insert before nonexistent elements?

Comment: @Barmar I think I get you, I should add `vec.begin()`, do you mean this? yes, this is my fault. But this is noy what I ask

Comment: @Barmar You say that the first argument to `insert` should be a *position*, i.e. an *index* in the vector? Yes? That's what the `indexes` array is, an array of indexes or positions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude His code is confusing, because he uses the variables `index` and `offset`, and both could mean the position in the vector. But the arguments are the same in C++ and Python insert, so I guess he understands it.

Comment: @Barmar what about now?

Comment: @roger Much better :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry, I have made some mistake in python code, it should output `[0, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, inserting at an index outside the list size is very forgiving, the implementation checks that the insert location is greater than or equal to `len(list)`, then the new item is inserted appended. In C++'s `std::vector`, this is not so. You will have to make that check yourself.

```
auto offset = 0;
for(auto x : indexes){
    if(x < vec.size())      //Is the selected index in range?
        vec.insert(vec.begin() + x, offset++);
    else
        vec.insert(vec.end(), offset++);            
}
```

---

Full example:

```
std::vector<int> indexes = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5};
std::vector<int> vec;

auto offset = 0;
for(auto x : indexes){
    auto iter = (x < int(vec.size())) ? vec.begin() + x : vec.end();
    vec.insert(iter, offset++);
}

std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

---

Outputs (As seen Live On Coliru ):

```
0 1 3 5 4 6 2
```

Comment: so so sorry, I just make mistake in python code, what I want is this:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bd0cb40dbf9ddb2

Comment: @roger, Ok then. There, you even have it.! . :-)... I hope this has answered your question, and your problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a vector without a specific size, it will be *empty* and all indexing into it (with or without iterators) will be *out of bounds* leading to *undefined behavior*.

In your loop you need to check that `indexes[i]` will not be out of bounds, and if it is then resize the vector appropriately or use `push_back` to append the value `offset` to the vector.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me, so sorry

Comment: @roger Think about this: If the vector is empty (which it is initially), what does `vec.begin()` return for iterator? It returns `vec.end()`! And the first thing you try to do int he loop? You want to insert an elements at the position `vec.end() + 1` which is out of bounds.

Comment: @roger The problem is indeed that the vector is empty or that you use an index that will be out of bounds, and that you need to append explicitly to the vector. [See here for a working example.](http://ideone.com/8Zai76)